# How to clean apache ignite free ram?

Tags: .net, caching, ignite, ram, apacheignite

I am facing a recurring issue with Apache Ignite where the application crashes approximately once a month due to continuous depletion of free RAM. I am utilizing Ignite cache for storing queryable entities in my application. Even after destroying the cache, the free RAM continues to decrease until it reaches about 3%-%1 just before the crash. Restarting Ignite brings the free RAM back to 100%.

In my Ignite configuration, I have set the eviction policy to "RANDOM_2_LRU."

```
<property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="name" value="Default_Region"/>
                        <property name="initialSize" value="#{256 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <property name="maxSize" value="#{80L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_2_LRU"/>
            <property name="swapPath" value="/swap"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
```

[before crush](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tpbP.png)
[after restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUf6h.png)

I would like to seek guidance on effectively managing and handling the free RAM to prevent these crashes. Is there a way to automatically clean the RAM or configure specific settings to mitigate this issue?

Any specific configurations or settings that can help address this RAM depletion issue?
Any insights or suggestions on managing memory effectively with Apache Ignite?

Comment: Which version of Ignite? How many nodes do you have? How much memory is available on your physical (or virtual) machines? What error message do you see when Ignite crashes?

Comment: Version : 2.13. One node and 80gb allocated memory for ignite. I can not find the error from the container logs. When writing operations does not respond, I check the logs and see free ram is almost %1, then I restart the service.  @StephenDarlington

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I think you're overcommitting your container. Your Ignite configuration looks fine, and it will not use more than 80Gb of *off-heap* memory.

However, Ignite doesn't only use off-heap memory. You also need to take into consideration the Java heap. Java itself takes up some memory, as does the operating system.

In short, if your container is configured to allow 80Gb of memory, your Ignite data region must be less than that. If your Java heap is 6Gb (you don't say), then I would allow around 10Gb total, meaning that your off-heap size should be around 70Gb.

Confirmed from your logs:

```
[WARNING][main][IgniteKernal] Nodes started on local machine require more than 80% of physical RAM what can lead to significant slowdown due to swapping (please decrease JVM heap size, data region size or checkpoint buffer size) [required=145736MB, available=128755MB]
```

With 128Gb pod size, I'd do something like 8Gb Java heap, 110Gb off-heap data region. More [tuning information](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/perf-troubleshooting-guide/memory-tuning#java-heap-and-gc-tuning) can be found in the documentation.

Comment: Ignite container has 128GB of RAM. In the Ignite configuration file, 80GB of memory has been allocated. I believe the remaining portion can be utilized for the Java heap. The main issue here is that despite specifying an eviction mode in the configuration, Ignite does not perform any cleanup when free RAM decreases. Is there a way for me to trigger the GC in such situations?

Comment: How much heap space have you configured?

Comment: Why would you need cleanup? Do you have something else running on the box?

Comment: Nothing else is running in the container. However, when I cache with TTL or manually destroy in Ignite, the freeRam percentage doesn't increase. This consistently causes a decrease in freeRam percentage, tracked in logs, regardless of data persistence. When it nears 0%, the container shuts down. Manually restarting makes freeRam 100%, allowing continued usage. Despite trying the off-heap eviction policy from Ignite docs in settings, I'm unable to get it to work. Logs show 'out of memory' warning with suggested actions: Enable eviction policies.

Comment: Can you please share the logs.

Comment: [ignite-log (Github Gist)](https://gist.github.com/furkansahin16/7e3d55726db14c8577256131eeb90c40) - @StephenDarlington

Comment: You've configured your JVM with 70Gb of memory (-Xmx70g). 70Gb heap + 80Gb off-heap = 150Gb, which is a lot more than 128Gb. It's unlikely your heap needs to be bigger than 10Gb. And you're not using the G1 garbage collector. See [the docs](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/perf-troubleshooting-guide/memory-tuning#java-heap-and-gc-tuning) for tuning information.

Comment: When I set the java heap to 10gb, with usage I got an error about java heap. Can you help me? It crushed again @StephenDarlington
[javaHeap](https://gist.github.com/furkansahin16/debe29bb42324a22fc353f5b529a4071)

Comment: Please share your JVM settings.

Comment: [jvmsettings](https://gist.github.com/furkansahin16/b13f8f70a3a56b4da125671e9896f887)

Comment: I have no idea why you would need so much memory, but it really doesn't change anything. If you need to increase the heap space, that's fine, but then _reduce_ the amount of off-heap. Don't configure Ignite to use more memory than you actually have.